# How to collect attributes and values in function

Tags: function, attributes, concatenation, xquery, marklogic

I am trying do this:
I want to do function which receives
one node as a parameter. and I it should return a string.
so I need to loop node and I don't know more details,
but I want to concatenate a new json type of string
and returns it.
but seems to be difficult, because I don't know xquery well.
my idea is

```
declare function local:Do_the_thing($my_node as node()*) as xs:string{
for ($element at $col in (attribute_list($my_node))
     let $complete_row_information := concat ("test", "test2");
return $complete_row_information
}
```

can someone say me, what is going wrong and how to fix it?
if this thing is not in a function it works

Comment: Which XQuery processor exactly, which XQuery version exactly do you use or target? And I don't see how `concat ("test", "test2")` would construct any JSON other than a plain string `testtest2`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I am new here, or after many years of pause.

Comment: Hi Martin, I am new here, or after many years of pause. I am using xquery version "1.0-ml". I can construct the string "testtest" if functionality is outside of function. but I want to use functions, for many reasons. My development environment is Marklogic qconsole, but my final product, will Marklogic rest-api extension. Because I want to to do everything without scheme. In final product, amount of attributes and values is flexibile. Just should do "foreach" with concatenation. if this system, lets you can write me also directly, to my private email, using my profile

Comment: I mean, that the string that I will print is json, and I even process it later with other languages. the json haven´t been a problem just function with 2 params, (input type, return type)  and foreach for concatenating data. (foreach loops attributes)

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking in this question or what the goal is. Do you want to return a string of all the attributes and their values from the node? How do you want them formatted in the string? Like `"attribute": "value", "next-attribute": "value"`?